# How to replace a space after a word with a line break (new line)?

Tags: neovim, key-bindings, init.lua, init.vim

In Neovim, I used the `J` command to join lines, and now I'm looking for a keybinding in normal mode that can do the opposite: replace the space after a word with a line break.

I've tried a few "revJ" (reverse J) plugins for Neovim, but I couldn't get them to work correctly, likely due to my configuration.

I'm wondering if there's a good solution for this inconvenience.

**My goal**:

```
"a, bb, ccc" => "a,
                 bb,
                 ccc"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `:substitute` command can be used to replace spaces with line breaks like this:

```vimscript
:s/ /\r/g
```

This will replace every space with a line break and repeat for every match on the line (`g` flag at the end)

It would be a little more robust (and a little bit more typing) to use:

```vimscript
:s/\s\+/\r/g
```

This will work on any sequence of whitespace (`\s`) repeated one or more times (`\+`). So tabs are also taken care of, and multiple spaces will still result in only one line break.

See `:help :substitute` for reference.

To create a *reverse J* mapping for regular use, you can use the following:

```vimscript
:nnoremap <key> <Cmd>s/\s\+/\g/g<CR>
```

Replace `<key>` with whatever key (sequence) you want for *reverse J*.

By the way, all of this will work both in Vim and in NeoVim.

Answer (score 0):

**The solution I found**:

The keybindig consists of the following commands: `f<space>s<enter><C-c>`

`f<space>` ... jumps over a word

`s<enter>` ... removes the space and inserts a new line character

`<C-c>`    ... represents the keybind Ctrl-C and for me, it exits the insert mode

This solution is meant for those who want a command that works on a line-per-line basis and doesn't just transform the whole text. This solution also works if there are multiple spaces between words.

Comment: You could also use `r<CR>` to replace a single character with a newline. No need to leave insert mode after that.

Comment: C-c and Esc behave differently. Prefer Esc.